# I wanted Encrypt PDF in a Such way that it open with given MAC ADDRESS Device

Tags: security, authentication, encryption, cryptography, mac-address

I am interested to encrypt my pdf file. I used a basic password authentication system. But still, it is not secure. Online tools like ilovepdf, etc brokes my file. I also tried to convert them into kindle, but again DRM remover comes into the picture. My target customer is going to open that file offline and he can open it without any password or certificates. I am thinking of combing my private key with his computer's MAC Address to decrypt the pdf document & again after decryption he should not able to copy it or use it elsewhere. If he gives a file copy to someone, a third party not should be able to open it with a known Original MAC Address. In short,

> I wanted to make a file, that should only be viewable on a specified
> mac address device with no OCR or immersive reader or text Selection or editable in any form including google docs.

Let me know how can I achieve this.
I have some knowledge of Encryption algorithms and cryptography with coding also.
Assume we have pdf file, target MAC Address before any processing.

Comment: It's not possible. 1) Anything that can bee seen on a computer screen can be copied. 2) If you use your private key for decryption, you have to give your private key to the customer - really bad idea 3) the MAC address of a computer is public within a network (at least to the router). Using public data as secret password is a bad idea. 4) It's easy to change the MAC address of a computer 5) Just knowing the MAC address of a valid machine is enough to decrypt the file.

Comment: @florian-metzger-noel it is possible, I have seen software working on this principle. Gujrat Education department has software that uses this technology to enter student credentials with authenticated devices only. I have met the software dev personally, he gave me this information.

Comment: 1) You can do nothing in locked incognito mode of any browser. Even you can't take screenshots. 
2)I have already knowledge about key distribution issues, and here we are not going to expose the key to customers directly.  There seems some logic.
3) about MAC addresses, All MAC addresses are hard-coded into a network card and can never be changed.   
4) Again it's not simple to change simple IP for normal users. So now he is going to change MAC?  
5) Sorry, but you missed it, I mentioned the possibility, and I cleared my aim and then put my idea. @florian-metzger-noel

Comment: 1) What browser are you referring to? Will your page only be available on that browser? 3) It's easy to change a MAC, here example for windows: https://www.wikihow.com/Change-a-Computer%27s-Mac-Address-in-Windows
4) security is not built to protect against simple users. If it's just about simple users, you don't need encryption at all 5) ok, got you wrong on that one, i guess

Comment: @florian-metzger-noel, you should not have any idea about proper software security. It deals with hardware BIOS. Logically changing MAC can give an advantage for network-based applications. Here my aim is to lock the pdf/file locally. Not Even on computers but also on android devices it is possible, I have a live example of it. I have an app that encrypted my device build number with a mac address, so even I uninstall the app it will revoke my access.  And your solution to MAC has been fixed in Windows 11 with high security. and on any browser, we can make pdf even in incognito mode.

Comment: Ok, it looks like you did a lot of research on that - so I guess it will be solid.